# Drupal 8 secure session

Tags: security

[image]In Drupal 8.5.X I see that the session cookie is only HTTPOnly and not secure. Any idea how to enforce the session cookie to be always secured?

Comment: It's not HTTPS? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP flag is being set by your browser as you're accessing Drupal over HTTP (and thus vulnerable to cookie hijacking). Drupal creates [2 different cookies](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21SessionConfiguration.php/function/SessionConfiguration%3A%3AgetName/8.2.x) (an unsecure HTTP one, and a secure HTTPS one) depending on what protocol it detects.

If you want only secure sessions, force HTTPS at the web server or application level (depending on your stack configuration).